# Statistic difference between ascended and legendary?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there any difference between the statistics of an ascended weapon and a legendary weapon ?

Now that you can select the category of statistics of a legendary, you can't see the stats in-game unless you have one, so I am not able to verify myself.

I would prefer in-game screenshots or a developer citation if possible.

Comment: The wiki is updated by the players, i.e. us. You can't make the assertion that the wiki is out of date and then also expect the rest of us to have any extra knowledge on top of that. We're the ones who update it.

Comment: I made no assertion, I didn't say it is not up-to-date. And I asked for a different source because I prefer actual in-game screenshots or developer citation rather than a player based wiki.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Shunwoo: Fair enough, withdrawing my down-vote. :-)

Comment: Asking for a developer citation is also off-topic, I'm afraid.  In-game screenshots, though, are totally what we excel in providing.

Comment: I can give you a (former) developer's citation: they don't have stat differences, they're all about sparkle and ponies and sunsets.

Comment: You could easily grab the game links from the wiki to view the items in-game, including their stats.

Comment: @Brian I did, but as I said, for the legendary it wasn't showing the stats anymore, but instead it was showing the possibility to select those stats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Vael has already answered, there is no difference in stats between a [Legendary](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Legendary) and an [Ascended](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ascended) weapon. They do the same damage and have the same level of bonuses. The main difference is that Legendaries have "fancier" visual effects (such as the skin, footprints, animations, particle effects) and that, when you're out of combat, you can double-click the weapon and select any [triple-attribute stat type](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Berserker%27s#Triple_attribute) (Berserker's, Soldier's, Knight's, etc.).

To confirm, compare [Zojja's Claymore](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Zojja%27s_Claymore), an ascended greatsword, from the wiki...

[image: Zojja's Claymore Stats]
[image: Zojja's Claymore]

...with a screenshot of my [Twilight](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Twilight) set to Berserker's stats:

[image: Twilight screenshot]

Both do **1,045 - 1,155** damage and, with the Twilight set to Berserker's, add **188** Power, **134** Precision and **134** Ferocity to your stats.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you can change the stats on legendary weapons. Also, I'm jealous of your Twilight (I've had everything I need except Dusk for almost a year now).

Comment: @Brian: Uhm, no I didn't (forget to mention you can change the stats), maybe you forgot to read the end of the first paragraph? :-) Good luck with your precursor, I'm glad I bought mine back when it was under 800g!

Comment: Oh, wow, you're right. How did I miss that? I'm still hoping they add in precursor crafting or scavenger hunt. I have no luck with drops (Mystic Forge or otherwise) and don't farm.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in the stat bonuses that a legendary will give vs. ascended. The benefits of the legendary are the visual effects, prestige, and ability to change your stats at will. (out of combat)

Comment: Can you give any source ?

Comment: @Shunwoo: Vael is correct, with the slight caveat that you can only change your stats while out of combat, not quite _at will_. You could've just looked up [Legendary weapon](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon) on the wiki, where it says, "They have the same stats as ascended weapons". Asking people to avoid answers from the wiki as it "may not be up-to-date" doesn't make sense, it's the official wiki and nothing about legendaries has changed recently.

Comment: @Amos M. Carpenter: As Koviko stated, the "official wiki" is player based, I'm asking for in-game or developer source. But if nothing has changed recently, then the answer is ok.

Comment: Your aversion to the wiki is likely unwarranted, it's a very reliable resource. Legendary weapons are pretty important to GW2 and you're not going to find misinformation on the Legendary Weapon page. (at least, it won't be there for long :}) I suppose you got what you wanted in the end with Amos's superior answer, though.